# Hiding/Canceling Hover Effect on Specific Images

Tags: html, hover, blogger

I just want to show some pictures without hover effect. I tried this but did not worked. I am newby in this coding area, and this is what I can do^^

```
<div>
<img border="0" src="IMAGE-URL" data-original-width="500" data-original-height="65"/>

<style>
    .post img:hover { visibility: hidden!important; }
</style>


</div>
```

I also tried {display :none}, but all of them effected all the images and caused flicker-like error.

Comment: I haven't quite understood your question. If you want to give hover effects to certain images add the styles under a certain class and assign that class to those images which should have that specific effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pointer-events` to disable hover effect

```
.post img:hover { pointer-events: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to assign two classes two your images and define different behaviours for hover states. This example illustrates the general logic where `div--nohover` class defines the standard style on hover:

```css
.div{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
.div:hover{
  background-color: green;
}

.div--nohover:hover{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div div--nohover"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand the logic. But It worked to some level. I am able to seperate the items thanks to your code. Still same flickering-like error. I tried to reset the values, but still giving hover effect.
`.div--nohover {
 -webkit-transition: all 0s ease; -moz-transition: all 0s ease; -o-transition: all 0s ease;
}
.div--nohover:hover {
 -o-transition: all 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0s;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}`

Comment: In this case, I would do the following `.div--nohover:hover { transform: none;}`

Comment: I tried similar one (writing to all sections "none!important"). Maybe this can be usefull, but I solved the problem. Anyway, thank you for your interest.